# android, Gallery view doesn't show my static images and crashes

Tags: android, crash, gallery

I want to have gallery view in my activity but i don't know whats happened to it that it doesn't show anything and crashes.

in on create method of activity, i have:

```
// initializing gallery view with predefined images
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(NewsList.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Then in separate java file, i have image adapter for that as follow:
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context mContext;

private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.g_adira,
        R.drawable.g_akim,
        R.drawable.g_alyah,
        R.drawable.g_atilia,
        R.drawable.g_awi,
        R.drawable.g_estrange,
        R.drawable.g_hafiz,
        R.drawable.g_hazama,
        R.drawable.g_jac,
        R.drawable.g_kristal,
        R.drawable.g_shila,
        R.drawable.g_stacy
};

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
    mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    attr.recycle();

    Log.i("ImageAdapter", "Gallery setupped successfully.");
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

    Log.i("ImageAdapter", "Position:" + position);

    return imageView;
}
```

}

XML code of gallery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Gallery 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. In logcat, i see my log which is put in constructor by I get null pointer exception and refers is to "gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));"

any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                 R.drawable.sample_1,
                 R.drawable.sample_2,
                 R.drawable.sample_3,
                 R.drawable.sample_4,
                 R.drawable.sample_5,
                 R.drawable.sample_6,
                 R.drawable.sample_7

        };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
            mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            attr.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear Raja, but i didn't understand what is the difference between my code and yours except you put the ImageAdapter class into activity. However, I shifted this class into my activity but the result is still crash because of nullpointer that i don't know comes from where :( Thanks again

Comment: nothing wrong in xml also can you post full code what you are using in .java file

Comment: correct, Actually this code was working fine yesterday, today i don't know what happened to it that through null pointer exception :) sorry the whole of code is very long. Thanks for your spending time for me.

Comment: try to clean the app and run,.,

Comment: The problem was because if include in xml UI of activity. I copy/paste the code and remove the include, now its fine. I don't know why it was working yesterday but today not didn't work!!!